# How do I set the value de/serializer for a Kafka KeyValueStore?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am storing the messages from a Kafka topic in a KeyValueStore so that I can query them later. I create a KTable as follows:

`@StreamListener
    public void process(@Input("input") KTable<String,MyMessage> myMessages) {`

I configured the consumer in my application.yml as follows:

**UPDATED de/serializer package**

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input:
  consumer:
    materializedAs: all-messages
    key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    value-deserializer: com.me.MyMessageDeserializer
    key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    value-serializer: com.me.MyMessageSerializer`

However, when I read from the KeyValueStore the keys are returned correctly as Strings but the values returned are Byte arrays not MyMessage. For some reason my custom deserializer is not being used. I tried to deserialize the message myself, but my deserializer crashed with an exception. I put a breakpoint on my serializer and it is never called. It is clear to me that neither my serializer or deserializer are being used.

What configuration am I missing so that my custom value de/serializer will be used? Do the de/serializers need to be in a specific package to be found?

Comment: Did you try to write the full package Name in front of your class? Or is it laying in root?

Comment: Try placing the complete package name before MyMessageDeserializer.

Comment: I have the full package name still did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong configuration keys were used in the application.yml. Instead of key-deserializer: it should be keySerde: and instead of value-deserializer: it should be valueSerde. Below is the correct configuration:

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input:
  consumer:
    materializedAs: all-messages
    keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    valueSerde: com.me.MyMessageSerde
  producer:
    keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    valueSerde: com.me.MyMessageSerde`